# Include lib in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I try include `ActionBarSherlock` in my Project and see red cross opposite the name lib

In project.properties i have next text:

`android.library.reference.1=D:\\Android\\work\\actionbarsherlock`

In `actionbarsherlock`properties CheckBox `Is Library` cheked.

Comment: If you are working on Eclipse, you should press alt+enter on your project and in the tab "android" add that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionBarSherlock` is a library project.

The red x indicates a broken link

I believe you have already downloaded the library project.

In eclipse click file, import , import existing code into workspace. There is a option to copy the same to workspace. click it. Click Finis and import into eclipse.

Now in your android project

Right click on your project goto properties choose android. Click browse and add and reference the library project.

snaps

[image]

Browse to the location where the library pproject is and import the same. Make sure you check copy into work space.

[image]

After importing into eclipse you can verify if its a library project. Right click goto properties android. You can see is library checked indicating its a library project
[image]

Then you reference the library project and you can see the green tick as below

[image]

Comment: @NickDevil it will. i have it working and i posted the snap of the same. the red cross you see means a broken link. try copy the library project yo the folder where your android project is and try

Comment: @NickDevil post your snap shots.

Comment: 1. http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0121/69/405470d7e1f92c775ab31df74b590769.png
2. http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0121/a1/c9aa8b1f7cba14d16efd6c12f621aca1.png
3. http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0121/17/3ddd2075851275a79d7c41271ae38f17.png
4. http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0121/89/62be17cf036897fd8e3d5b41e4d73b89.png
5. http://i57.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0121/e3/bdcab8bd857d55b96aab339f64918fe3.png

Comment: @NickDevil the red x indicates its a broken link can't find the library @ that location. that is your probblem. Make sure you have the library also in the same folder as your android project. that is why i had the  2nd screen shot posted. copy the project to workspace

Comment: But first green indicates :( and sherlok can not be bad

Comment: it has happened to me many times. pls try the suggestion once.

Comment: i try 100 times :) no result

Comment: @NickDevil if you do it right it will work. good luck i can;t comment any further. I have posted snap shots it should be enough to get your problem solved. google for a guide and follow it

Answer (score 0):

your project and sherlock library should be in same directory.

Comment: Not necessarily, you can import the library to your workspace