# Using ABS in android

Tags: android, api, android-actionbar, shared-libraries

I want create a program with action bar sliding. I read many tutorials and i write a sample program but my problem is: getActionBar() required Api level 11+ and i want my program supports api level 8+. I searched and i know, i should use ABS([Actionbar sherlock link](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)). I donwload this but this is not a jar file that i add to my program. How can i use this? i searched but i cant find a good answer and step by step answer. 
Thanks for advise
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionBarSherlock` is a library project. You need import the library into workspace and reference the same in your andorid project. Have a look @

[Include lib in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261294/include-lib-in-eclipse/21261702#21261702)

The other option is to use `AppCompat` from the support library extend `ActionBarActivity`, use Theme.AppCompat and use `getSupportActionBar()`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

To setup

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, i can add library to my project. but my class extend MapActivity and for using getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar(), i should SherlockFragmentActivity . How can i solved this problem? how can i extend MapActivity and use getSupportActionBar()? Thanks

Comment: switch to google maps api v2 instead of mapsforge if you are using that. I am not aware of how to incorporate this with that. ALso this question is answered. Accept this and ask a new question

Comment: @user3209380 also you are required to mention everything relevant  in the question. You haven't and you may attract downvotes. pls add proper tags and relevant details next time you ask a question

Comment: @user3209380 are you referring to the MapActivity of google maps api v2 or mapsforge coz i remember the last question you asked was related to  mapsforge